# AWS SAM with Java - building a thin jar

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, gradle, aws-sam

I'm using AWS SAM to build a Java Lambda. I'm also using Gradle for the packaging.

I'm trying to use Layers to separate my dependencies and my code.

When I run `gradle build` in my code folder, I get a nice clean build folder with no dependency jars. This uses the `packageSkinny` target.

When I run `gradle build` in the deps folder, I get the desired result too - all my dependencies, no code. This uses the `packageLibs` target.

However, when I run `sam build`, I get a build folder that has the dependency JARs in both folders - the layer and the function.

How do I **stop** AWS SAM from including all my dependencies in the main function layer, and get a nice thin zip file for my compiled code?

Function Gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform('software.amazon.awssdk:bom:2.16.60')
    implementation platform('com.amazonaws:aws-xray-recorder-sdk-bom:2.11.0')
//    implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:lambda'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-xray-recorder-sdk-core'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-xray-recorder-sdk-aws-sdk-v2'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-xray-recorder-sdk-aws-sdk-v2-instrumentor'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-core:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-events:3.11.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:[2.17.1,)'
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:[2.17.1,)'
    runtimeOnly 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j18-impl:[2.17.1,)'
    runtimeOnly 'com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-log4j2:1.5.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
//    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.6.0'
}

task packageFat(type: Zip) {
    from compileJava
    from processResources
    into('lib') {
        from configurations.runtimeClasspath
    }
    dirMode = 0755
    fileMode = 0755
}

task packageLibs(type: Zip) {
    into('java/lib') {
        from configurations.runtimeClasspath
    }
    dirMode = 0755
    fileMode = 0755
}

task packageSkinny(type: Zip) {
    from compileJava
    from processResources
}

sourceCompatibility = 11
targetCompatibility = 11

build.dependsOn packageSkinny
```

SAM Template:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  HelloWorld

  Sample SAM Template for HelloWorld

Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 20

Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: HelloWorldFunction
      Handler: HelloWorld.Handler::handleRequest
      Runtime: java11
      Description: Handler to process and encode the voice print
      Architectures:
        - arm64
      MemorySize: 512
      Policies:
        - AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
        - AWSLambda_ReadOnlyAccess
        - AWSXrayWriteOnlyAccess
        - AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole
      Tracing: Active
      Layers:
        - !Ref libs
  libs:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
    Properties:
      ContentUri: layers
      Description: Dependencies for the HelloWorld function
      LayerName: HelloWorld-lib
      CompatibleRuntimes:
        - java11
      CompatibleArchitectures:
        - arm64
    Metadata:
      BuildMethod: java11
      BuildArchitecture: arm64

Outputs:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Description: "Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunction.Arn
```

Folder structure:

```
❯ tree
.
├── README.md
├── events
│   └── event.json
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
├── layers
│   └── build.gradle
├── out.json
├── HelloWorldFunction
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── src
│       ├── main
│       │   └── java
│       │       └── HelloWorld
│       │           └── Handler.java
│       └── test
│           └── java
│               └── HelloWorld
│                   ├── AppTest.java
│                   ├── TestContext.java
│                   └── TestLogger.java
├── samconfig.toml
└── template.yaml
```

Comment: I'm curious about this myself, mostly to avoid uploading a larger JAR each time. Probably should set up CI/CD  with CodeDeploy instead. However, it might work with the Gradle "provided" keyword instead of implementation. You use that for WARs when the JAR is in already in the app server lib dir.

Comment: I did actually solve this in the end by using a Makefile. But, the latest release of SAM solves it natively for Maven builds by doing exactly that - using the "provided" keyword! I'll write up my answer when I get time.